# Getting undefined error when trying to add array

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-services, nativescript-angular

When user click on button, I have to add the value inside sample array. Below i have posted the code:

**sample_apps.json:**

```
{
     "user": {
        "userId": "maxwell",
        "sample": [

        ]
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array";
import { AppService } from "~/app.service";
import { Sample } from "~/sample";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public obsArr: ObservableArray<Sample> = new ObservableArray<Sample>();


    constructor(private samService: AppService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.obsArr = this.samService.sampleApps();



    }
    public addSample() {
        console.log("Addding Value");

       this.obsArr[0].samArr.push(3);
       for (let i = 0; i < this.obsArr.length; i++) {
        console.log("Get(" + i + ")", this.obsArr.getItem(i));
    }
    }

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<StackLayout>
<Button text="Add Sample" (tap)="addSample()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Sample } from "~/sample";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array";
var samJsonData = require("~/sample_apps.json");

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    public sampleApps(): ObservableArray<Sample> {

        console.log("SampleData", JSON.stringify(samJsonData));

        var sampleArrayList: ObservableArray<Sample> = new ObservableArray<Sample>();

         let sample : Sample = new Sample();
         sample.sampleUserId = samJsonData.user.userId;
         sample.samArr = samJsonData.user.sample;
         sampleArrayList.push(sample);

        return sampleArrayList;
    }

}
```

**Sample.ts:**

```
  import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array";


export class Sample{

    sampleUserId : number;

    samArr: ObservableArray<any> = new ObservableArray<any>();;    
}
```

Getting **runtime error**:

> CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an
>   object (evaluating 'this.obsArr[0].samArr')

**Expected output:**

when user click on Add Sample button, i have been expected output like below:

```
{
     "user": {
        "userId": "maxwell",
        "sample": [
           12
        ]
    }
}
```

When ever user click on button, number has to be added into that sample array.

Comment: I believe it's just an init problem. Array should be defined like yourArray: youtType[] = [];

Comment: @JacopoSciampi can you elaborate more or else post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed:

```
this.obsArr[0].samArr.push(3);
```

to this:

```
this.obsArr.getItem(0).samArr.push(3);
```

to solve this issue.

Now i got my expected result in console:

```
 Get(0) {
"samArr": [
3
],
"sampleUserId": "maxwell"
}
```

Comment: Glad you sort it out. You must use `getItem` as it's extended version of JavaScript Array as you could read in the docs - https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/observable-array